# Linq version of string array any in enum list

Tags: c#, linq, enums

Currently I have:

```
public enum ApplicationRoles
{
        Undefined = 0,
        Basic = 1,
        Admin = 2
}

// within a method:

bool? isAuthorized = null;
string[] allowedRoles = { "Admin" };
List<ApplicationRoles> userRoles = new List<ApplicationRoles>();

userRoles.Add(ApplicationRoles.Admin); 

foreach (string role in allowedRoles)
{
   foreach (ApplicationRoles appRole in userRoles)
   {
     if (appRole != ApplicationRoles.Undefined)
         isAuthorized = role.ToLower() == appRole.ToString().ToLower();
   }

   if ((bool)isAuthorized)
     break;
}
```

isAuthorized would return true in this example.

How can this be converted to a Linq statement?

Comment: I think your code is broken anyway :) If the user has Basic and Admin and the required role is Basic, won't it return false? (... although it's fine if the user can only have one role)

Comment: Updated to just test for Admin

Comment: @Josh your changes to strings and single values versus enums and arrays make it difficult to understand what the real requirements are - either post your code as-is (enums aren't that much more complex that strings) or provide detail as to what your requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `Any` method:

```
allowedRoles
.Any(role => user.Roles.Any(r => r != ApplicationRoles.Undefined &&
                                 role.ToLower() == r.ToString().ToLower()));
```

If you wanna check only for one role there is no need for `allowedRoles` array:

```
user.Roles.Any(r => r.ToLower() == "admin");
```

Comment: I was trying to keep the example simpler, it needs to support an array.

Comment: I like your solution, but it doesn't deal with ignoring the default selection (Undefined) if (appRole != ApplicationRoles.Undefined)

Comment: @Josh okey, added that check as well.though I dont understand why do you need that check.. just don't include into allowedRoles at the first place

Comment: Defensive coding because this is part of security logic. if someone accidently adds Undefined to allowedRoles (which is a param) it is a double check.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store any of your values as hardcoded strings; that's what the enums are for, after all.

```
var allowedRoles = new HashSet<ApplicationRoles> { ApplicationRoles.Admin };
bool isAuthorized = userRoles.Any(r => allowedRoles.Contains(r));
```

This approach also works fine with arrays.

```
var allowedRoles = new[] { ApplicationRoles.Admin };
var userRoles = new[] { ApplicationRoles.Basic };
bool isAuthorized = userRoles.Any(r => allowedRoles.Contains(r));
```

Comment: I'm not, I wanted to keep the example simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var allowedRoles = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ApplicationRoles))
    .Cast<ApplicationRoles>()
    .Except(ApplicationRoles.Undefinied); // allow all except undefined

bool isAuthorized = userRoles.Any(r => allowedRoles.Contains(r));
```

this way you don't need to mess with any string comparison.